# Are there any filters to add additional columns to the list table on edit-comments.php?

Tags: admin, columns

I'm trying to modify the display of the `edit-comments.php` admin page and I'm not seeing any filters in it comparable to `manage_posts_columns` etc.

Is there an easy way to do this? I'm thinking the only real way to go about doing this is to extend **WP_Comments_List_Table** with my own class, overwrite the `get_columns` and other related functions, and just add my own page to the admin menu which uses this new class in the same way that edit-comments.php uses **WP_Comments_List_Table**.

Is there an easier way to do this that I'm just not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that there is no easy way to get that done yet because the only hook i found is **manage_comments_custom_column** and that is an **action** hook and not a **filter** hook so you can't add columns like manage_posts_columns. so as far as i can tell the long way here is the only way. but you can almost duplicate the default edit-comments.php and extending small classes like wp_post_comments_list_table and more.

Answer (score 0):

This is a old post, but
I found there is a easy way now.
use 'manage_edit-comments_column' action and 'manage_comments_custom_column' filter.
https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/comments-table-columns.html